# Matplotlib error- I got an error message as in below I would appreciate if I can get response how to solve this

Tags: python, matplotlib

## I goet an error message as below. I tried to import matplotlib from my jupyter notebook
I would really appreciate if I can get an answer to solve this issue

ImportError: cannot import name 'artist' from 'matplotlib' (C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_*init*_.py)

Comment: You might want to switch to Python 3.x. Python 2.x is long dead, and matplotlib requires Python 3.7 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

```
conda install matplotlib --force
```